# Order Publisher table after replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-replication

I've got two database servers. The remote server replicates to the local server. The data that is sent is basically an XML description of transactions. The two database servers compile this XML data onto a secondary database, and then a text based XML file is sent to another server, which, for reasons that cannot be avoided, cannot have direct contact to the other two servers. The order of the rows that are selected for the XML file is vital. Basically, if server A generates a row, then B generates 2 rows, then A generates a second row, we need to be able to select '"ABBA." At this point, the origin of the rows is not important, only the order. I know an identity column will not work well to order by, since in replication we would need to seed the column at two different ranges. A timestamp doesn't really work either, since there are several rows generated very quickly, almost simultaneously, and the timestamp does not have enough decimal places to get an accurate order by. How can i get the rows in the correct order, AFTER replication?

Comment: I'm confused. Two database servers, one local and one remote.  Is the remote one "A" and the local one "B"? They both feed a third server?

Comment: No, B is the remote, feeds to local A. So, if the order the rows are created at each node is A1, B1, B2, A2; that is the order i need to be able to select them from the A node.

Comment: So if these are the assumptions:

1. B is remote.
2. A is local.
3. Both write lots of records quickly.
4. Both are authoritative.
5. Replication isn't fast enough to keep up with local writes.

Then I think I would work towards changing one of those assumptions.  Otherwise like you I can't think of how to order them after replication.  Using time would be incredibly hard since the two machines would have to have their time synced perfectly.

Maybe shift the authority to a third party.  That might slow things down too much, but worth considering.  The ID comes from not A or B.

Comment: Yeah, those assumptions are all correct. Might just have to go back to the drawing board on this one.